# final variable case in switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement, case, final

```java
        final int a = 1;
        final int b;
        b = 2;
        final int x = 0;

        switch (x) {
            case a:break;     // ok
            case b:break;     // compiler error: Constant expression required

        }
        /* COMPILER RESULT:
                constant expression required
                case b:break;
                     ^
                1 error
        */
```

Why am I getting this sort of error? If I would have done `final int b = 2`, everything works.

Comment: defining like `final int b;` will make it as variable.

Comment: thus before you init it it has null value

Comment: and finally it initialized, why this switch expression that doesn't accept variables?

Comment: using a switch equivalent to if - else, this is not good use map instead, it accepted any Object as a key.

Comment: Roman, what are you talking about? :)

Comment: @RomanC are you sure you commenting the right question? Just asking.

Comment: @RomanC The compilation errors are part of the question...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`b` may not have been initialized and it is possible to be assigned multiple values. In your example it is obviously initialized, but probably the compiler doesn't get to know that (and it can't). Imagine:

```
final int b;
if (something) {
   b = 1;
} else {
   b = 2;
}
```

The compiler needs a constant in the `switch`, but the value of `b` depends on some external variable.

Comment: But couldn't compiler "see" that I initialized it on next line (after declaration), so it shouldn't worry about it initialized somewhere else?

Comment: @Furlando no, compiler can't do that. Imagine that instead of this `if` clause you use a complex method that retrieves the value from database or another external source.

Comment: @Furlando After creating `final int a = 1;` and using it like `x=3*a*a` compiler will optimize your code and replace `a` with `1` in your byte code, that is why you can use it in `case a:break;` but since `b` can be declared later like `final int a = new Random().nextInt()` compiler wont be able to predict what `b` will be and will not be able to replace it with some constant which is required for `case` parameter, that is why you see your error.

Comment: I think this answer is slightly wrong (cc:@Furlando), because Java compiler will most certainly see that variable is initialized for sure. If you try to use variable, when compiler can't be 100% sure it has been initialized, you get compiler error. However, it does not do similar code flow analysis about the the *value*, so it will only treat `final` as constant (allowed in `case`), if it's initialized in the declaration statement.

Comment: That's basically what I meant. Probably I didn't state it that clearly?

Comment: @Bozho Well, your answer starts with "`b` may not have been initialized..." so yeah, maybe re-word it a bit. Compiler *does* know if `b` is sure to be initialized or not, when it's used.

Comment: hm, it doesn't. What if there's if(something) {b = ...}. Then in the switch the compiler doesn't know if b is initialized. And because if that it can't inline it.

Comment: @Bozho If there is a code path which may leave a *local* variable uninitialized before its value is used (anywhere, not just switch-case), you get compiler error. Try it... Issue of the question is difference between compile time (`final int I=1;`) and runtime (`final int I; I=1;`) initialization of a `final` variable, not uncertainity of initialization before use.

Comment: well, yes, but I think both are the same thing. The latter can't be compile-time initalized because the compiler is uncertain :)

Comment: @Bozho, to clarify the difference, consider this: final int b = something ? 1 : 2;  So, the value of b is still runtime dependent. Will this be allowed?

Comment: @Bozho,Furlando ask for Switch statement..your solution say about if-else statement !!

Answer (score 15):

The case in the switch statements should be constants at **compile time**. The command

```
final int b=2
```

assigns the value of `2` to `b`, right at the compile time. But the following command assigns the value of `2` to `b` at **Runtime**.

```
final int b;
b = 2;
```

Thus, the compiler complains, when it can't find a constant in one of the cases of the `switch` statement.

Comment: So what can I do instead?

Answer (score 3):

The final variable without value assigned to it is called a blank variable. A blank final can only be assigned once and must be unassigned when an assignment occurs or once in the program.

In order to do this, a Java compiler runs a flow analysis to ensure that, for every assignment to a blank final variable, the variable is definitely unassigned before the assignment; otherwise a compile-time error occurs

That is why when the compiler compiles the switch construct it is throwing constant expression required because the value of b is unknown to the compiler.