# What is the difference between the two following lines of java code?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Excuse me for my ignorance. I couldn't understand the difference between the following seemingly similar lines of code.

1. `final int num1 = 1;`
2. `final int num2;` `num2 = 2;`

What makes the `num2` not eligible for a switch case constant?

```
    switch (expression) {
        case num1:
            System.out.println("Case A");
        case num2:
            System.out.println("Case B");
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are using this that you're getting an error? As long as you declare and initialize num2 before switching on it there should be no problem.

Comment: The answers here and the discussion in the comments may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255270/final-variable-case-in-switch-statement Also marking it as duplicate.

Comment: Yep, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16255341/2358786) is the answer. num1 is the compile-time constant, while num2 is not.

Comment: @NicolásCarlo Does it mean that num2 is not assigned a value at compile time?

Comment: @Phoenix Yes, num2 IS NOT assigned at compile time. It is done run-time. Are you clear now ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To the Java Language Specification we go. A [`switch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) statement's `case` labels are defined as

```
SwitchLabel:
    case ConstantExpression :
    case EnumConstantName :
    default :
```

Your `num` variable is not referring to an `enum` constant name, so let's ignore that. What is a [`ConstantExpressions`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)? The JLS again defines it

> A compile-time constant expression is an expression denoting a value
>   of primitive type or a `String` that does not complete abruptly and is
>   composed using only the following:
>
> - Literals of primitive type and literals of type String
> - [...]
> - Simple names (§6.5.6.1) that refer to **constant variables** (§4.12.4).

So the primitive `int` value `2` is a constant expression. You could do

```
switch {
    case 2:
}
```

Now we want to know the relation with the use of [`final`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) and **constant variable**.

> A *blank* `final` is a `final` variable whose declaration lacks an initializer.
>   [...]
>
> A variable of primitive type or type `String`, that is `final` and
>   initialized with a compile-time constant expression (§15.28), is
>   called a **constant variable**.

So that last quote is referring to a non-*blank* `final` variable, ie. one that has an initializer.

So

```
final int num1 = 1;
```

is a constant variable.

And

```
final int num2; 
num2 = 2;
```

is not and therefore cannot be used in a `case` label.

Answer (score 0):

So, to answer your question : `num1` is compile-time constant, so compiler essentially can replace it with `1` :

```
switch(whatever) {
    case num1: // will produce same bytecode as

    case 1: // num1 was replaced by compiler 

}
```

Compiler can't assume same about `num2`, as explained with simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16255341/2358786)

Note, that you would have same problem with `num1`, have you initialized it with non-constant, for example : `int num1 = new Random().nextInt();`

Answer (score -2):

in num1 you initialize it right away, in num2 you dont right away, you assign it it's value later on

Comment: It is clear as daylight. But what is the point in num2 being not eligible as constant in switch case?

Comment: @Phoenix it's because the compiler and switch statements are type sensitive and by finalizing it you make sure it can't change value or type. Like if you use it on a jcombobox you have to specify the box to be final before you can run a switch statement

Comment: I don't buy that explanation... Question is good, this explanation lacks reference (to the JLS, probably)