# A final constant not accepted in switch case

Tags: java, switch-statement, java-7, final

I would like to know the difference between the 2 declarations inside a method add() as in below.

```
final int c;
c = 20;
```

and

```
final int c = 20;
```

I think that both are final variables for which, I cannot reassign any new values. Here is the method that is treating the above declarations differently.

```
void add() {
        final int a = 30;
        final int b = 10;
        final int c;
        c = 20;

        switch (a) {
        case b + c:
            System.out.println("In case b+c");
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

The above method doesn't compile at all, complaining that

> **constant expression required case b+c**

If the variable c is declared and initialized in one line, like `final int c = 30;`. It works.

Comment: Look at this http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java) as it states in the link, final is used when the variable will not be changed. You declare the variable but not set it's value... Then below that you set it's value... You can't do that..

Comment: Both are equivalent (I think) in the sense that you get to assign c once. If you want to maintain the logic in your switch, do "final int d = b+c;" and "case d:" in your switch.

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255270/final-variable-case-in-switch-statement?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [JLS #4.12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) defines *constant variables* as (emphasis mine):

> A variable of primitive type or type `String`, that is final ***and initialized with a compile-time constant expression***, is called a constant variable.

In your case, `final int c = 20;` is a constant variable but `final int c; c = 20;` is not.

Answer (score 2):

Java compiler replaces a `final` identifier with its value if it is declared & initialized in a single(same) statement, otherwise identifier is kept as it is and initialized by jvm at run time for `blank final` variable. You can see this by opening `class` file. `switch` statement permits `final`, but not a `blank`, variable to be used as a `case` value.

```
final int a = 20; // concrete final variable
switch(a){}
#=> gets changed by compiler as the following:--
switch(20){}

final int a; // blank final variable
a = 20;
switch(a){}
#=> compiler leave it for jvm to initialize 
switch(a){}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are initializing and declaring it separately you  are getting that error, do it at the same time and it work

Answer (score -1):

final variables can't be re-evaluated again runtime, If you want to use switch case you can't do like (b+c) in case clause,
instead of this do use this one,

```
void add() {
    final int a = 30;
    final int b = 10;
    final int c;
    c = 20;
    final int cmp=b+c;
    switch (a) {
    case cmp:
        System.out.println("In case b+c");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Now this will work fine for you,

Comment: Compile error: `case expressions must be constant expressions`. Take a look at the accepted answer, an expression with final variables is accepted here. A non-final variable is not accepted.

Answer (score -2):

You have to initialize local variable before use..

Comment: It is initialized before use. The problem is it's not initialized at declaration time.